How does McCormick envelope work for inequality constraints?
I have a question regarding the McCormick envelope in mathematical optimization.
The McCormick envelope allows to create a convex relaxation for a bilinear term.
Given the bilinear constraint $w = x \cdot y$ with bounds $x_L \leq x \leq x_U$ and $y_L \leq y \leq y_U$ one can relaxe this constraint into the following four constraints:

$w \geq x_L \cdot y + x \cdot y_L - x_L \cdot y_L$
$w \geq x_U \cdot y + x \cdot y_U - x_U \cdot y_U$
$w \leq x_U \cdot y + x \cdot y_L - x_U \cdot y_L$
$w \leq x_L \cdot y + x \cdot y_U - x_L \cdot y_U$

But what if one has an inequality constraint instead, i.e. $w \leq x \cdot y$ or $w \geq x \cdot y$.
How does the envelope work in these cases?

Do you know how to convert an inequality to an equality constraint?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend By introducing a slack variable so $w \leq x \cdot y$ becomes $w = x \cdot y - s$ and $w \geq x \cdot y $ would become $w = x \cdot y + s$ with $s \geq 0$. Would I use on this equality constraint the McCormick envelope?

I'd certainly do so. And yes, that is correct

You can simply define a new variable, $u\triangleq xy$, and rewrite
$$
u = xy, \\
w \leq u.
$$
The inequality is now linear and you can use the McCormick envelopes for the equality.
